# When enabling php_curl extension it's showing error

Tags: php, filemaker

I install wampserver on Windows 7 (64 bit) on server where some another service are also installed like IIS etc. So I change the port from 80 to 8080 in httpd.conf.I install 2.4 version. So here when I try to enable php_curl it's showing error

> **Could not execute menu item (internal error)[Exception] Could not perform sevice action**

In apache_error I found that.... it's showing

```
php warning: PHP startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\Program FilesFilemaker\\Filemaker Server\\Web Publishing\\publishing-engine\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll'-%1 is not a validwin32 application.\r\n in unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Use `netstat -a -b` in cmd.exe look for any apps that are using port 80,8080 ect also dont forget to restart apache when after making changes to config

Comment: I checked out that and 8080 id used bye httpd.exe

Comment: If wampserver's httpd is not running then you have some other WAMP stack installed. Also if you dont use IIS disable it.

Comment: But I cant disable IIS.And I dnt understand "If wampserver's httpd is not running then you have some other WAMP stack installed."

Comment: Really? Im sure you have a reason other then you cant. Anyways basically only **one** service can listen on any one port.

Comment: @LozCherone:I m trying to perform this for main server  where lots of services are running.So thast why I cant do that.So now what should I do?

Comment: You are getting a PHP startup message that says that _php_curl.dll is not a valid win32 application_ – so this should have _nothing whatsoever_ to do with used ports or what other (server) services are running on the machine. It might rather be a problem with compatibility (API vs DLL version) or something like that. I’d recommend downloading/installing PHP fresh to make sure there’s no mismatches of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have some issues here because you have FileMaker server installed and it has it's own PHP stack installed and it has that set in your Path variable. So when you try to starup WAMP, windows is trying to intialize the curl.dll in the FileMaker php directory.

I highly advise not trying to run both WAMP and FileMaker server on the same machine if you are using IIS and FileMaker CWP/IWP/XML.

If you absolutely have to, you're going to need to edit your path variable but you're probably going to break the filemaker server's php install doing so. I haven't ever gotten it to work correctly.

@user3068785
You would write your php separately, then you would call that php through a web portal on a layout. It is common to do things such as have PHP parse some xml from an API using parameters from FileMaker. You can calculate out the address you want to call using a calculation and concatenating your parameters.

FileMaker PHP is just an API library which proviced for the ability to create PHP scripts that can interact with or just display data from FileMaker.

for example, lets say you have a FileMaker database named "Contacts" and you host it locally on your server at: 192.168.1.25. Your username is Ralph and your password is blankets. In php, you can make a simple function to do something like:

```
    <?php

require_once ('FileMaker.php');
define('FM_HOST', '192.168.1.25');
define('FM_FILE', 'Contacts');
define('FM_USER', 'Ralph');
define('FM_PASS', 'blankets');


$fm = new FileMaker('TSG', '192.168.1.10', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $result = $fm->listLayouts();
    foreach ($result as $layout){
        <--do something with your layouts that have been parsed into an array -->
    ;}

 ?>
```

The API goes much deeper with being able to call records, specific fields, allow you to pull valuelists, edit records, create records etc.

Comment: You do not have to use FileMaker's installation of PHP with FileMaker CWP (not sure about IWP). You can copy the API to your site and refer to it with an include statement so you don't need to worry about what installation you're using.

Comment: Though this is true, I've had issues with being able to call the require_once('FileMaker.php') and get it to pull on a consistent basis. If you are using CWP/IWP it's best to use the FMPHP stack.

Comment: @VikingBlooded how you execute FileMaker.php in filemaker?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I see that When I installed Filemaker Server that time its also installed PHP. After that Again I installed wamp server.So If i called a php file than its supports comes from filemaker server 's PHP folder. Here in this PHP folder's php.ini i enable the php_curl extension.